# Add dynamic text to WM_CREATE in C++ using variables

Tags: c++, winapi

Been hacking away on this for quite awhile and now I'm finally down to a single issue. I'm using VS 2019.

The application I'm creating gets dynamic input from 4 souces. It took awhile, but I was able to add dynamic text to WM_PAINT doing the following:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{    
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  HDC hdc;
  
  TCHAR myMessage[10000];
  _tcscpy_s(myMessage, CA2T(st1.c_str()));
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

  TextOut(hdc, 25, 20, myMessage, _tcslen(myMessage));

  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  break;
}
```

Even though I could add dynamic text, I could not add multiple lines and the text always showed with a white background. Finally gave up and moved on to trying something else.

I got the following to work using WM_CREATE and WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, but I cannot figure out how to make the text for each line dynamic (read from a variable). I've defined IDC_USER_LABEL at the top of the program.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{                                   // Create text and exit button
  // The following will be simplified using tests and loops once I get variables to work 
  int textHStart  = 20; int textLineSpace = 16;
  int textVStart1 = 20; int textVStart2 = 60; int textVStart3 = 100;  int textVStart4 = 120; 
  string string1 = "This is the first line";
  string string2 = "This is the second line";
  string string3 = "The third line which is  followed by...";
  string string4 = "this line and is the end of the text written to the screen xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.";  // 59 chr
  int textLength1 = string1.length() * 10;
  int textLength2 = string2.length() * 10;
  int textLength3 = string3.length() * 10;
  int textLength4 = string4.length() * 10;

  HINSTANCE hIns = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
  DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE;
  hCtl = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), TEXT("This is the first line"),                   dwStyle, textHStart, textVStart1, textLength1, textLineSpace, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
  hCtl = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), TEXT("This is the second line"),                  dwStyle, textHStart, textVStart2, textLength2, textLineSpace, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
  hCtl = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), TEXT("The third line which is  followed by..."),  dwStyle, textHStart, textVStart3, textLength3, textLineSpace, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
  hCtl = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), TEXT("this line and is the end of the text written to the screen xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), 
                                                                                                dwStyle, textHStart, textVStart4, textLength4, textLineSpace, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
  // Create the exit button
  HWND hButton = CreateWindow(_T("button"), _T("Exit"), dwStyle, 385, 250, 60, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hIns, 0);
  return 0;
}

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
{
  HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;

  SetTextColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 0, 0));
  SetBkColor(hEdit, RGB(154, 228, 243));

  return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
}
```

I want to change TEXT in CreateWindowEx to use a variable instead of a hard coded string. Is it possible or do I need to start over from scratch?

Comment: Don't hack away trying to learn an API. Find some documentation. The stuff you're looking for is basic and should be in any competent docs you find (`SetWindowText`, `DrawText`; static text controls in windows can be multiline).

Comment: I have been reading the documentation. That's why I've gotten as far as I have. Sad that some people feel the need to berate people when they ask a question.

Comment: When you use phrases like "Been hacking away" you give the impression that you're not following a tutorial, and are just trying to figure it out. Using more accurate phrases ("I've been reading thru with _documentation/tutorial_ and I'm having this problem") would show that you're putting in some effort and increase the chance you'll get a helpful answer
.

Comment: Instead of `TEXT("This is the first line")` use `string1.c_str()`.

Comment: Oh my gosh Jonathan, that's exactly what I needed! I tried multiple things, but not that. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, in your `WM_PAINT` handler, you can get rid of `myMessage` and just use `st1` as-is: `TextOutA(..., st1.c_str(), st1.size())`. For multiple line text, you could have used `DrawTextA()` instead, with the `DT_WORDBREAK` flag.

Comment: I tried using st1.c_str() in TextOutA, but could not get it to work. It might have been the st1.size() that was messing me up. I still have the code from when I was trying to use WM_PAINT. Now that I have it working with WM_CREATE, I will go back and trying what you mentioned. I'm sure there will come a time when WM_CREATE will not be a good choice so I should learn both ways.

Comment: [Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api). You will want to go with the third format, always (unless you have a very *specific* reason to use the second). You **never** want to use the first, as your code is doing.

Comment: @IInspectable Not sure what you mean about the format. My project is setup to use Unicode. Can you let me know what you mean by using the third format instead of the first?

Comment: First line from the linked document reads: *"Windows API functions that manipulate characters are generally implemented in one of three formats"* followed by the list of formats.

Comment: @IInspectable Now I understand. I took another look at the link and see 'A Unicode version with the letter "W" used to indicate "wide"'. A lot of this does not sink in easily, but I will parse through the pages and links and try to follow your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @IInspectable OK, I think I got it. CreateWindow is the original function, which was replaced with CreateWindowEx. When CreateWindow is used, it calls CreateWindowEx but you are not using the "Ex" benefits. From what I can figure out, CreateWindowExW creates an extended child window and "is identical to the CreateWindow function." (I might be a little off on some of it, but I understand the importance.)

Moving forward, I will check for a "W" version and do my best to use those functions when possible.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I finally ended up with. Works like I wanted with plenty of possibilities for optimizing and enhancing.

```
case WM_CREATE: {                                   // Create text and exit button
  int textHStart  = 20; int textLineSpace = 16;
  vector < int > textVStart = {20,60,100,120,160 };
  vector < string > newStrings;
  newStrings = getDynamicData();                    // Get the strings for output

  HINSTANCE hIns = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
  DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE;

  for(int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); i++) {
    hCtl = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), newStrings[i].c_str(), dwStyle, textHStart, textVStart[i], newStrings[i].length() * 10, textLineSpace, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
  }

  // Create the exit button
  HWND hButton = CreateWindow(_T("button"), _T("Exit"), dwStyle, 385, 250, 60, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hIns, 0);
  return 0;
}
```