# Passing hFont (CreateFontA) to CreateWindowEx

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

SOLVED!!!

My original question was if the CreateFont function would work with the CreateWindow function. Everything I found in documentation lead me to believe it only worked with the text function.

Since I was unable to implement the suggestions I was offered and wasn't making any progress on my question, I took a new approach. I created my test code so i could easily switch between changes I made in WM_CREATE: and WM_PAINT:. Now it is easier to hack out what I find in documentation, searching and things that pop into my head.

The following is what my test code looks like. Adding and removing the comment for styleSelection lets me select what I am working on.

Global: HFONT hFont;

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  HDC hdc;

  string styleSelection = "WM_CREATE";
 //styleSelection = "WM_PAINT";

  switch(uMsg) {
     case WM_CLOSE: {
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      DestroyWindow(hWnd);
      break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND: {
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    }
    case WM_CREATE: {
      HINSTANCE hIns = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
      if((styleSelection == "WM_CREATE") && (hFont = CreateFontA(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, 1, 0, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT("DONTCARE")))) {

        int textHStart = 20; int textLineSpace = 16;
        vector < int > textVStart = { 20,60,100,120,160 };
        vector < string > newStrings;
        newStrings = getDynamicData();                    // Get the strings for output

        for(int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); i++) {
          CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("Static"), newStrings[i].c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, textHStart, textVStart[i], newStrings[i].length() * 10, textLineSpace, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_USER_LABEL, hIns, NULL);
        }
      }

      HWND hButton = CreateWindowA(_T("button"), _T("Exit"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 385, 250, 60, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hIns, 0);
      return 0;
    } 
    case WM_DESTROY: {
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: { 
      HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;
      SetTextColor(hEdit, RGB(0, 0, 0)); 
      //SetBkColor(hEdit, RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)); 
      SetBkMode(hEdit, TRANSPARENT);
      return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
    }
    case WM_PAINT: {
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);


      if((styleSelection == "WM_PAINT") && (hFont = CreateFontA(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, 1, 0, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT("DONTCARE")))) {
          HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
        
        HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        //SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        
        int index = 7;                       // Vertical spaces and number of lines for the array
        const char* cpaText[7] = { "Hello,","", "What I want to do", "is to format this text." };

        for(int iLoopCounter = 0; cpaText[iLoopCounter] != 0; iLoopCounter++, index += 20) {
          TextOutA(hdc, 5, index, cpaText[iLoopCounter], strlen(cpaText[iLoopCounter]));
        }
        SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
      }
      EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
      break;
    }
  }
  return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

////---- this is  the data to be printed.
vector < string > getDynamicData() {
  vector < string > retvec;
  retvec.push_back("This is a test.");
  retvec.push_back("I am trying to change the text");
  return retvec;
}
```

The solution I finally came up with is in the Answers section.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code, but I'm assuming that your `hFont` variable is declared within the body of the `WndProc`. That means that it is lost (and the font handle leaked) as soon as it goes out of scope. You need to declare variables external to `WndProc` if you want them to survive.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter  Originally the hFont variable might be part of the issue, so I made it global awhile back. (Also, thank you for letting me know to update my original question instead of creating answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution:

One of my issues was TextOut in WM_PAINT was not using dynamic text. Looking back at an earlier resolved issue using Jonathan Potter's suggestion in [Add dynamic text to WM_CREATE in C++ using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504444/add-dynamic-text-to-wm-create-in-c-using-variables), I finally realized the same would work for TextOut.

After I got TextOut to work with dynamic text, the next option was to keep WM_CREATE for the standard font style or migrate everything to WM_PAINT. I decide migrating to WM_PAINT would be the cleaner solution. The following is what I finally ended up with:

Global: HFONT hFont;

```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HDC hdc;

    string styleSelection = "standardFont";
    styleSelection = "specialFont";

    switch(uMsg) {
      case WM_CREATE: {
        if(-1 == DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_CREATE, wParam, lParam))
          return -1;
        hFont = CreateFontA(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, 1, 0, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT("DONTCARE"));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LPARAM)hFont);
      }
      break;case WM_CLOSE: {
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
      }
      case WM_COMMAND: {
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
      }
      case WM_DESTROY: {
        //DestroyObject((HFONT)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        DeleteObject((HFONT)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, wParam, lParam);
      }
      case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC hEdit = (HDC)wParam;
          SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT); 


        if(styleSelection == "standardFont") {
          SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));   

          int textHStart = 20; int textLineSpace = 16;
          vector < int > textVStart = { 20,60,100,120,160 };
          vector < string > newStrings;
          newStrings = getDynamicData();                    // Get the strings for output

          for(int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); i++) {
            TextOutA(hdc, textHStart, textVStart[i], newStrings[i].c_str(), newStrings[i].size());
          }
        }
        else {
          DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_PAINT, wParam, lParam);
          hFont = (HFONT)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
          HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
          SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)); 

          int textHStart = 20; int textLineSpace = 16;
          vector < int > textVStart = { 20,60,100,120,160 };
          vector < string > newStrings;
          newStrings = getDynamicData();                    // Get the strings for output

          for(int i = 0; i < newStrings.size(); i++) {
            TextOutA(hdc, textHStart, textVStart[i], newStrings[i].c_str(), newStrings[i].size());
          }
          SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
          DeleteObject(hFont);

        }


        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
      }
      default: {
        return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
      }
```

The above code also implements some of what SoronelHaetir recommendation. I will look a little more into following the rest of SoronelHaetir's suggestions
I still need to work on possible memory leak issues and a few other smoothing out items, but this works for what I want to do. All it took was reading, patience and being persistent enough to hack away until I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `CreateWindow` during your `WM_PAINT` handler.

Instead, what you need to do is save the font you create in your `WM_CREATE`  handler and then use that font later when you get a `WM_PAINT`. `GetWindowLongPtr`/`SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_USERDATA` is the provided canonical means for performing this kind of data save.

For example:

```
LRESULT WINAPI MyWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {
  case WM_CREATE:
  {
    if(-1 == DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_CREATE, wParam, lParam))
    return -1;
    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(...);
   SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LPARAM)hFont);
  }
    break;

  case WM_DESTROY:
    DestroyObject((HFONT)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, wParam, lParam);

  case WM_PAINT:
  {
    DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_PAINT, wParam, lParam);
    HFONT hFont = (HFONT)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    ...
  }
    break;

  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

  return 0;
}
```

It would also be possible to create the `HFONT` in whatever code actually creates your window and pass that `HFONT` as the `lParam`  parameter to `CreateWindow` and then save it as described while handling `WM_CREATE` (rather than actually creating the `HFONT` while handling `WM_CREATE`).

Comment: @ SoronelHaetir  I tried to implement your suggestions, but I'm still unable to get the font to change. Originally, I did not post all of the code, but now it's all listed.

Comment: Still not having any luck. Not finding any documentation on what I am trying to do and there does not appear to be any past postings that address changing fonts when using the CreateWindowEx function. I will continue to update my original post with either the suggestions I got or with other things I try.

Answer (score 0):

for textboxes it's done with

```cpp
    HFONT newFont = CreateFont(22, 0, 0, 0,0 , FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_NATURAL_QUALITY,
    DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DECORATIVE, L"Lucida Console");
    ::PostMessage(hc,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)newFont,(LPARAM)0);
```

and you should create all this elsewhere

and use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`

add this `::PostMessage(hc,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)newFont,(LPARAM)0);` to `for` cycle you have, to the end. But not with `hc` ofc

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion. I created the following, but I was unable to get it to work.    case WS_EX_COMPOSITED: {
      hFont = CreateFont(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, 1, 0, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT("DONTCARE"));
      ::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)0);
      break;
    }

Comment: no , `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` is not bad to add to main window style. it's side-notes

Comment: so use `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE|WS_EX_COMPOSITED` instead of  `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`